# Don't grey out Disabled TextInput in React Native Elements

Tags: react-native

I am trying to change the color of disabled React-native-elements component TextInput. Default behaviour is to grey out everything but I would like to have solid black color of the text even if it's disabled. Has anybody tips of how to do it?

Same question as [Don't grey out Disabled Input in React Native Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996370/dont-grey-out-disabled-input-in-react-native-elements) but for TextInput component.

**TextInput** don't have a **disabledInputStyle** prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `editable`. It won't grey out it.

```js
<View style={styles.app}>
    <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={"values"}
        editable={false}
    />
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: Strange. In my code editable gray out  the text. Could you share the codesandbox here?

Comment: @FabioDev, Working as expected?

Comment: I managed to make it work with Editable, and setting the color style.